# Change background of specific row

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm using rhandsontable in R shiny and I would like to change the color of the row with "Sum" in the first column. Since the number of rows is not fixed, selecting the "Sum" row based in its row number does not work. I have tried the attached code, which unfortunately does not work.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
runApp(list(server=
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

     CF_amt <- as.data.frame(matrix(0.0, nrow=5, ncol=10));
     CF_type <- data.frame(source = c("Row1","Row2","Row3","Row4","Sum"),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
     CF_names <- c("source","C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10");
     CF_tbl <- cbind(CF_type,CF_amt);

     values <- reactiveValues(data = CF_tbl)
     
     output$table <- renderRHandsontable({ 
       rhandsontable(values$data,rowHeaders = NULL,colHeaders=CF_names) %>% 
         hot_cols(fixedColumnsLeft = 1, renderer = "
             function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
               Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
               if (col == 0) {
                td.style.background = '#F0F0F0';
               }
               else if(this.instance.getData()[row][0] == 'Sum'){
                td.style.background = '#F00000';
               }
            }"
       ) 
    })
  })
,ui=
  shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",
    tabPanel("HOT",
       fluidPage(fluidRow(
         column(12,rHandsontableOutput("table"))
      ))
   )
  ))
))
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have a javascript error. Try changing

```
this.instance.getData()[row][0]
```

to

```
instance.getData()[row][0]
```

because `instance` is passed as parameter to your render function.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks ! That solves the problem. Actually, I think that I have tried that as well. However, now it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChrisW You should mark this answer as the answer to your question.